# How to make FTP upload function with backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, upload, ftp, backgroundworker

here is my code

```
public bool FTPUploadFunct(string uploadto2, string newskinlocation2)
    {
        bool FTPUploadFunct = true;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "uploading....";
        MessageBox.Show("uploading");
        try
        {
            //delete old file
            FtpWebRequest requestFileDelete = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadto2);
            requestFileDelete.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTPUser20", "1234");
            requestFileDelete.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

            FtpWebResponse responseFileDelete = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDelete.GetResponse();

            //upload new file
            FtpWebRequest requestFTPUploader = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadto2);
            requestFTPUploader.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTPUser20", "1234");
            requestFTPUploader.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(newskinlocation2);
            FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

            int bufferLength = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

            Stream uploadStream = requestFTPUploader.GetRequestStream();
            int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

            while (contentLength != 0)
            {
                uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            uploadStream.Close();
            fileStream.Close();

            requestFTPUploader = null;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            FTPUploadFunct = false;
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
            MessageBox.Show(status);
            int errorNumber = (int)ex.Status;
            if (errorNumber == 550)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("550");
            };
        }
        return FTPUploadFunct;
    }
```

I use it when

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        uploadto = ("ftp://" + severip + ":21/" + "IMG/" + username + ".png");

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Workker run!!!");
        bool resualtUp = FTPUploadFunct(uploadto, newskinlocation);
        if (resualtUp == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("True");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("False");
        }
    }
```

message I get when I click button6 is "Workker run!!!"
and nothing after that,***My cursor is still default(Never change!!!, why ?), I'm super newbie for backgroundWorker sorry :(
please help me....

Comment: attach a debugger and set a breakpoint in your catch function and on this line `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "uploading....";` I don't expect that to work because you no longer are on the UI-Thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a split second, the cursor changes to the wait cursor.

The reason is, that the `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` call will run the worker in another thread. So the next line is executed immediately afterwards.

The solution would be to remove the `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;` line from the `button6_Click` method and add it to a `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

**EDIT:**

To set the text of the label or do anything with a control (enabling/disabling a button, etc.) use `Form.Invoke()`.

Example for setting the label's text to "uploading....":

```
this.Invoke(() => {
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "uploading....";
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so how to show progress for toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "uploading....";

Comment: private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            bool resualtUp = FTPUploadFunct(uploadto, newskinlocation);
            if (resualtUp == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("True");
                MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate()
                { toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Upload finish!"; };
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }
I got messagebox "True"
toolStripStatusLabel1 text doesn't change.....

Comment: @Patipan Are you actually invoking your delegate? Are you executing `this.Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);`? Instead of creating a delegate, you can just use the lambda expression in my post, looks way cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all what you  have to do is something  like  this  (with some tuning for the code )

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;  
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default; 
    }
 void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

and  in your code  you should  add this  line of  code

```
while (contentLength != 0)
            {
                //here you  should do  
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(contentLength / fileInfo.Length));  
                uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }


 Hope  this  help
```